# How create a spam filter in express.js or how to filter objects based on the word in the key values?

Tags: javascript, express, search, filter, backend

I want create simple spam filter. I dont have an inbox yet but I was thinking when the emails are recived I could make a GET request and filter the object based on the words mentioned in the message.
If the posted object is

> [{"id":"1"  "email":"xyz@gmail.com",    "cc": "abc@gmail.com",
> "message": "You have a chance to win a lottery and be a millionaire"
> },
>
> {"id":"1"  "email":"qwet@gmail.com",    "cc": "ghj@gmail.com",
> "message": "hello how are you doing" } ]

I want to filter the object with id===1 that contains a combination of words "lottery","win","millionaire" in the message

I have come across Naive Bayes spam filtering algorithm but I don't know how to integrate it with Express.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're just looking to check a string against an array of words for matches; this has nothing to do with emails or express. Leave out anything irrelevant and you will find existing solutions much easier.

Comment: To be fair, this would imho be a bad solution for spam filtering. Perhaps nice for learning, but not for practical use. If someone legit talks about any of those subjects in an email, you'll end up with lots and lots of false positives.

Comment: @icecub You are right. I thought of that too but I can't come up with a better solution. If you can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: I'm not an expert on spam filtering, so I honestly wouldn't be able to tell you much about it. One thing that would be a great starting point would be to verify if the domain used in the sender's mail headers matches the IP address in those headers. Anyone can easily change those headers and "send" email from any email address they like. I could easily send an email from bill[at]gates[dot]com. But my ip address would not match looking up gates[dot]com. So this is a huge red flag.

Comment: Another tip would be to lookup lists of known spam / advertisement websites / servers. Such lists are used by uBlock / adBlock+ for example. Then check the message body if it contains URLs pointing at any of those. This would be another pretty reliable red flag. Obviously also install a decent anti-virus software to check message attachments. Other than that, you'd have to do more research yourself. As that's pretty much where my ideas / expertise on spam filtering ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can do this way by using filter()**

```
posted_object.filter(
  (item) => item.id != 1 || !item.message.includes("lottery") || !item.message.includes("win") || !item.message.includes("millionaire")
);
```